# AWS MWAA Cloudformation stack creation failed with NotStabilized

Tags: amazon-web-services, airflow, aws-cloudformation, mwaa

Cloudformation returning below error while creating AWS MWAA cluster:

> Resource handler returned message: 'Creation failed' (Request Token:
> 123..., HandlerErrorCode: NotStabilized)

IAM Policies, Roles and Subnet configurations are good
We are trying to create MWAA cluster in a VPC where all subnets are private. So there are no NAT Gateway / instances connecting to external world. Webserver access mode is private only.

Please let me know what are the things we have to consider to solve this issue.

Comment: What is your template?

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Private subnets and private web server mode are fine, but there are a few pitfalls. Have a look at [AWS' troubleshooting page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/t-create-update-environment.html#t-create-environ-failed).

Make sure you have a S3 gateway endpoint in place.
Check the logs (see same link).

In case you provide a requirements.txt be aware of the fact that MWAA needs internet access to install the python packages from pypi.org. To overcome this you can provide wheel packages with your plugins.zip.